# Join 3rd table inside the WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to extend a 2 table join query to join 3 tables. I'm using PDO

```
SELECT tb.product, COUNT(tb.ID) AS nums FROM items tb LEFT JOIN itemCode cod ON tb.ID = cod.codeID WHERE tb.product = :product AND cod.name = :cName
```

The above 2 table join works. My question is, how do I match `itemCode`'s `availabilityID` column to `tblC`'s `stockID` column and add it to the `WHERE` clause with same query to get the result?

So basically I want to check if the `availabilityID` column of `itemCode` table match with `stockID` column of `tblC` table.

EDIT: table structure:

```
**items table**
ID   |  product 

**itemCode table** 
codeID   |  name 

**tblC table**
stockID
```

Comment: Can you show the structure of the tables?

Comment: What columns has tblC table?

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis thanks. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in your question you want to match `availabilityID` with `stockID`, this is what the query does. However, the `availabilityID` does not show up in your edit.

```
SELECT tb.product, COUNT(tb.ID) AS nums
FROM items tb
LEFT JOIN itemCode cod ON tb.ID = cod.codeID
JOIN tblC stock ON stock.`stockID` = cod.`availabilityID`
WHERE tb.product = :product AND cod.name = :cName
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this is not what I exactly wanted. See my edit. I'm trying to match `ID` to `codeID`  and `name` to `stockID`